# Adonis Lucid ORM Not Returning data

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, adonis.js

I am new to Adonis JS so extremely sorry for the Stupid Question.

I have the default setup of Adonis JS with Mysql Database and everything working.

I have created a simple usertest route where I am returning JSON of user with ID: 1.

Below is the code for the same

```
Route.get('/usertest', ({ response }) => {
  const User = use('App/Models/User')
  let data = User.query().where('id', 1)
    .first()
  console.log(data)
  return response.status(200).json(data)
})
```

But it is returning and empty object

Raw Response:

```
{}
```

Console Log Statement Response:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I am unable to understand what am I missing here.

Note: I tried `let data = User.find(1)` but it did not work.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick note, at least you have to execute the query asynchronously.

I mean, you have to replace:

```
let data = User.query().where('id', 1)
    .first()
```

by:

```
let data = await User.query().where('id', 1)
    .first()
```

Of course, this mean you have to precede the function arrow with `async`:

```
Route.get('/usertest', async ({ response }) => {  
  // rest of the code
  let data = await User.query().where('id', 1).first()
  // rest of the code    
})
```

Comment: It resolved the problem, Thank you, Just a note, need to add `async` for the function where we are using `await`

Comment: By the way, you can use a shortcut for your query: `let data = await User.find(1)` @AkshayKhale

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to miss "await" when you start working with async-await frameworks. Just a suggestion on the query whenever you want to find one object it is good practice to use ORM's predefined function. In this case

const user = await User.findBy('id',1)

this will return the first object it finds with the given id. You will find more options and help in knex.js docs http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where